# Ignite failing to start on windows

Tags: ignite

I downloaded ignite latest binary release 2.7. After executing bin/ignite.bat, it gives below error:

Windows IP config below:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::69b8:bb9b:2988:278a%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.4
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::bac1:a2ff:fe32:7104%15
                                       192.168.1.1

````
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to get SPI attributes.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:278)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.start(GridIoManager.java:262)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1682)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:986)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2038)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1730)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1158)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1076)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:962)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:861)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:731)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:700)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:348)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to resolve local host to addresses: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.getNodeAttributes(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2159)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:261)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No network addresses found (is networking enabled?).
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.resolveLocalAddresses(IgniteUtils.java:2087)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.resolveLocalAddresses(IgniteUtils.java:2046)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.getNodeAttributes(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2142)
        ... 14 more```
````

Comment: What is your network configuration? Can you please show `ipconfig` command output?

Comment: @alamar - Ipconfig updated in original post

Comment: Can you try setting IgniteConfiguration.localHost to 192.168.1.4?

Comment: @alamar - If you can help me with where can I set this? Also everytime the address  changes. Now its 192.168.1.5. Does it mean everytime I will need to change this

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @alamar for helping on the issue.

Whenever you see this error. Do an ipconfig and get the ip address

Update the config xml in IGNITE_HOME/config directory(in my case default-config.xml)

````
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">  
     <property name="localHost" value="192.168.1.5"/>
</bean>```
````

Comment: Hey Gopal ! I have got the same issue. But this solution has not resolved it. Did you do anything else to get past this issue?

Comment: No @SandeepShanbhag - the above resolved my issue. You might want to ensure you are making changes to the correct config file. All the best !